# Radio Buttons in Dynamicaly Generated Angular Form

Tags: angularjs, forms, radio-button

https://gist.github.com/djdaniels90/948704c58242c4bb08b5

I am having trouble with a dynamically generated quiz structure.  I am aware of $parent. scope.  I have attempted to implement it but the form is still not working as desired.  I have linked the gist site; any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Each question is a form in itself and the entire quiz is a form of question forms.  Each question form contains x number of possible answers.  Furthermore, a quiz can have y number of questions.  Therefore we have a loop within a loop; ie: we are creating some nested child scopes.

Ultimately, each question can only have one answer, ie: only one checkbox can be clicked for each subforms.  I can rather easily hack together a method using pure JS or jquery to grab the form elements but I know there is a way to do this in Angular, I am pretty close I believe but can't get the last little bit.  Ideally, I would like either the questions to update corresponding models, which could be created in a array within the controller.  Or the form submit action to upload the entire quiz data.

Any help on where I am going wrong would be great.

Comment: can you explain what is wrong with it or can you create a plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: I started you off with a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fACdq8DGvJel9An87GyA?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the plunker.  A bit better than gist for this, I'l be sure to use it from now on, instead of gists.

Comment: As for the problem.  There are two: I would like the form submit to eventually trigger a post request to a backend server with the results of the quiz.  This is not hard and I can easily do this but, the problem I am having is actually getting the user input; or having the user input update a model.  The models are being dynamically generated therefore I don't have the concrete name to reference them.

Comment: As for passing this to a server, you can send a answer each time a radio button is clicked (to save user progress) using ng-change and a function attached which passes question# and answer#. Or you can pass the entire quiz by iterating just before Submit and send an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one attribute and need a variable for assigning answers to.

The **NAME** attribute takes care of the grouping and the **model** cannot be the question object itself, but rather an attribute of the question itself.

```
<input type="radio" name='{{question.question}}' ng-value="{{answer}}" ng-model="question.answer">
```

Here's a working version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fACdq8DGvJel9An87GyA?p=preview